# Why doesn't scala infer the type members of an inherited trait?

Tags: scala, scala-2.10

I have a group of types that each have their own type member:

```
sealed trait FieldType {
    type Data
    def parse(in: String): Option[Data]
}
object Name extends FieldType { 
    type Data = String 
    def parse(in: String) = Some(in)
}
object Age extends FieldType { 
    type Data = Int 
    def parse(in: String) = try { Some(in.toInt) } catch { case _ => None }
}
```

And I have a group of types that operate on sets of the `FieldType`s (using boilerplate rather than abstracting over arity):

```
sealed trait Schema {
    type Schema <: Product
    type Data <: Product
    val schema: Schema
    def read(in: Seq[String]): Option[Data]
}
trait Schema1 extends Schema {
    type D1
    type FT1 <: FieldType { type Data = D1 }
    type Schema = Tuple1[FT1]
    type Data = Tuple1[D1]
    def read(in: Seq[String]) = schema._1.parse(in(0)).map(Tuple1.apply)
}
trait Schema2 extends Schema {
    type D1
    type D2
    type FT1 <: FieldType { type Data = D1 }
    type FT2 <: FieldType { type Data = D2 }
    type Schema = (FT1, FT2)
    type Data = (D1, D2)
    def read(in: Seq[String]) = {
        for {
            f <- schema._1.parse(in(0))
            s <- schema._2.parse(in(1))
        } yield (f, s)
    }
}
```

I thought I could use this system to elegantly define sets of fields that are meaningful because scala would be able to infer the type members:

```
class Person extends Schema2 {
    val schema = (Name, Age)
}
```

However, this doesn't compile! I have to include definitions for all the type members:

```
class Person extends Schema2 {
    type D1 = String; type D2 = Int
    type FT1 = Name.type; type FT2 = Age.type
    val schema = (Name, Age)
}
```

How come scala can't infer D1,... and FT1,...? How can I refactor this so I don't have to specify the type variables in `Person`?

Note: Once I have a better understanding of macros, I plan to use them for the `Schema` types. Also, I'd rather not use shapeless. It's a great library, but I don't want to pull it in to solve this one problem.

Comment: Could this be a limitation of type inference with structural typing?  Have you tried restructuring using generics instead?

Comment: This does work with generics on `FieldType`. However, having a generic param on field type made working with `FieldType` pretty messy. I tried separating `FieldType` into two types: `FieldType` and `Parses[Data]`, but then the compiler couldn't do the inference again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By declaring this:

```
val schema: Schema
```

you specify that `schema` must of type `Schema` *or any of its subtypes*. Hence, knowing the type of `schema`, you cannot infer `Schema` because it could be any *supertype* of `schema.type`.

You can solve your problem by reversing completely the thing: define the type alias in terms of `schema.type`:

```
trait Schema2 extends Schema {
    type Schema = (FieldType, FieldType)
    type FT1 = schema._1.type
    type FT2 = schema._2.type
    type D1 = FT1#Data
    type D2 = FT2#Data
    type Data = (D1, D2)
    def read(in: Seq[String]) = {
        for {
            f <- schema._1.parse(in(0))
            s <- schema._2.parse(in(1))
        } yield (f, s)
    }
}
```

(Not sure it will *actually* work, but in theory this should typecheck.)

Comment: With this approach, it looks like the compiler can't figure out that `FT1#Data` is the same thing as the result of `schema._1.parse()`. I'm trying different variations on this though, but it seems like making `type FT1 = schema._1.type` should really help.

Comment: @DanGallagher I think this works if you declare `type Schema = (FieldType, FieldType)` (instead of `<:`).  IntelliJ complains about what you said here, but the compilation works.

Comment: Oh waw, I did not really believe it myself ^^ Thanks for the fix, @Ben Reich.