# How to match on type member in function signature in Scala?

Tags: scala

For obscure reasons due to a specific library I'm using involving macros and serialization, I have chosen to try to use type members instead of type parameters for a class (background: [Is there a way to use ClassTags with the Autowire library in Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49634031/is-there-a-way-to-use-classtags-with-the-autowire-library-in-scala))

```
sealed trait Command {
  type M <: CommandMetaData
  val meta: M
}

final case class SysCmdMetaData(
// ...
) extends CommandMetaData


// How to guarantee cmd.M <: SysCmdMetaData
def runInSystem(cmd: Command){
  //...
}
```

Is there a way to do this statically? I think using type classes and context bounds is one option, but I feel it is a bit heavy handed since I'm already using subclassing here. Perhaps the better option is just to make metadata a trait, and embrace object oriented more fully and create all kinds of variations of Command based on which traits are mixed in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define the function argument with a refined type:

```
def runInSystem(cmd: Command { type M <: SysCmdMetaData }) = { }
```

Note that unlike type parameters, [type members are not inferred by default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24983882/why-doesnt-scala-infer-the-type-members-of-an-inherited-trait). The following code will fail:

```
scala> val cmd: Command = new Command {
  type M = SysCmdMetaData
  val meta = SysCmdMetaData()
}

cmd: Command = $anon$1@830b8a5

scala> runInSystem(cmd)
<console>:15: error: type mismatch;
 found   : cmd.type (with underlying type Command)
 required: Command{type M <: SysCmdMetaData}
       runInSystem(cmd)
                   ^
```

You'd have to either:

- Use some named subclass of `Command`, where `M` is statically fixed to an appropriate type.
- Pass an anonymous subclass instance directly to `runInSystem`:

  ```
  runInSystem(new Command {
    type M = SysCmdMetaData
    val meta = SysCmdMetaData()
  })
  ```
- Manually prescribe the type member of the variable you pass to `runInSystem`:

  ```
  val cmd: Command { type M = SysCmdMetaData } = new Command {
    type M = SysCmdMetaData
    val meta = SysCmdMetaData()
  }

  runInSystem(cmd)
  ```
- You can also define a type alias with a type parameter:

  ```
  object Command {
    type Aux[M0 <: CommandMetaData] = Command { type M = M0 }
  }

  val cmd: Command.Aux[SysCmdMetaData] = ???

  runInSystem(cmd)
  ```

Comment: I opted for your first suggestion (since I already had the subclasses floating around), but it is great that you listed so many alternatives.